# Introductory data trend analysis with R

Tags: r, time-series

I am new to the data analysis world and am struggling to find relevant articles / examples related to what I'm trying to do. I have a data set that is like this, for example how many apples are sold at the store each day (where T0 is closing) (stored in a CSV):

```
Day,T0,T-1,T-2,T-3,...,T-10
2015-04-18,500,400,300,200,...,0
2014-04-17,800,700,200,100,...,0
...
```

So far I have been able to read the file in and plot a simple line graph for a single day.  Now I want to do more,

- Plot all days on a single line graph against each other
- Trend analysis (e.g., whats the average sale count in the last hour)
- Prediction work (e.g., based on morning sales, whats expected in the last few hours)

I am not looking for specific help with this specific example, but rather examples or case studies online to help guide me to the functionality I need in R.

Answer (score 1):

- Plotting in **R** is very convinient using the `ggplot2` package.
  Have a look at `?ggplot2::geom_line` and http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_line.html to see some examples

  - For trend analysis there are lors of functions. You can use the base *R* functions. In your example (assuming your data is called `df`) `mean(df$T0)` will give you the avg. sales count in the last hour.
  - There are lots of predition methods implemented in **R**.
    Easy to understand are linear models see `?lm` and maybe use the `forecast` package.

Hope this helps you with your very broad question.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into ggplot2, it sounds like what I am after!